# R: substract values in a column from different starting values

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
a<-c(1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1)
b<-c(0,200,0,0,0,45,0,0,30,0,0)
c<-c(3400,3403,3407,3408,3412,3423,3436,3245,3234,3456,2345)
df<-cbind(a,b,c)
df
```

My desired output would look like:

```
       a   b    c   d
 [1,]  1   0 3400   0
 [2,]  1 200 3403   0
 [3,] -1   0 3407   0
 [4,]  1   0 3408   5
 [5,] -1   0 3412   0
 [6,]  1  45 3423   0
 [7,] -1   0 3436   0
 [8,]  1   0 3545  22
 [9,]  1  30 3554   0
[10,]  1   0 3556   2
[11,]  1   0 3565  11
```

I want to get the difference of values in column c calculated from  c values where the corresponding values in column b are not 0 until a new non zero column b value is reached, then this new value should be the new starting value. Another criterion is that the  value in column  a has to be the same if the difference in column c is calculated. E.g. d value of row three is 0 and not 4, since column a value of row two (the starting row) is 1 and the a value of row three is -1.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Since I don't understand your calculation: could you clearify based on your given example how to do this?

Comment: column d value == 5 comes from: 3408-3403, the code should do this calculation since the row 2 value of column b is not 0 and column a value of row 4 is the same as in row 2. (= -1).  Then the column d value == 22 comes from 3545-3423, since column b value in row 6 is not 0 and the column a value of row 8 is the same as in row 6  ( = 1). And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(count = cumsum(b!=0))  %>%
  group_by(count, a) %>%
  mutate(m = n(),
         d = ifelse(m > 1 & any(b != 0), c - first(c), 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-count, -m)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 11 x 4
       a     b     c     d
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0  3400     0
 2     1   200  3403     0
 3    -1     0  3407     0
 4     1     0  3408     5
 5    -1     0  3412     0
 6     1    45  3423     0
 7    -1     0  3436     0
 8     1     0  3545   122
 9     1    30  3554     0
10     1     0  3556     2
11     1     0  3565    11
```

Note: I don't think your test data and your desired output-data are consistent. I used the data shown below.

### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1), b = c(0, 
200, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0), c = c(3400, 3403, 3407, 3408, 
3412, 3423, 3436, 3545, 3554, 3556, 3565)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right, there is a typo in the example. One more question:  Is there also a possibility to do the same but only if the value in column a is different than the value from the corresponding "starting row"? So kind of a  anti - group_by for column a ?

Comment: Interesting question. There surely is a way, but I have to think about it...

Comment: Not sure if this works in all possible constellations of data: `df %>% group_by(count = cumsum(b!=0)) %>% mutate(a_new = ifelse(b!=0, a, NA_integer_)) %>% fill(a_new) %>% mutate(m = n(), d = ifelse(m > 1 & any(b != 0) & a != first(a_new), c - first(c), 0))`.